# In C++, what is the advantage of accessing a Class/Struct by pointer OR by instance

Tags: c++, pointers, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

In C++, what is the advantage of Implementation 1 over Implementation 2 indicated below. Since both are a kind of pass by reference, won't the memory be allocated from HEAP, in both the cases ? If that is the case, what is the advantage of one over the other.

Secondly, which methodology is better - Pass by value OR Pass by reference. When, one should use Pass by Value and when one should use Pass by reference.

**Implementation 1:**

```
main()  
{        
    struct studentInfo { int Id;  int Age; };    

    *studentInfo tom;  
    populateInfo (tom );  

    printf ("Tom's Id = %d, Age = %d\n", tom.Id, tom.Age);  
}

void populateInfo ( struct studentInfo & student )  
{  
    student.Id = 11120;  
    student.Age = 17;  
    return;  
}
```

**Implementation 2:**

```
main()  
{  
    struct studentInfo { int Id; int Age; };   

    *studentInfo *tom = new studentInfo;
    populateInfo (tom );  

    printf ("Tom's Id = %d, Age = %d\n", tom->Id, tom->Age);  
}  

void populateInfo( struct studentInfo *student )  
{
    student->Id = 11120;  
    student->Age = 17;  
    return;  
};
```

Comment: 1: The `*` on the line that declares `tom` seems out of place. If present, it causes a compile error. 2: No, the memory won't be allocated from heap in both cases. In the first case, it is allocated on the stack (`tom` is a local variable in `main()`). In the second case, the memory will be allocated from the free store (`tom` is a pointer that is initialized by the `new` operator).

Comment: A small side note: In C++, `struct foo {...};` is a real type. So you don't have to prepend `foo` with `struct` like in C.

Answer (score 2):

There's probably one main difference between passing by address/pointer and passing by reference:

- A reference cannot be null.

Which method might be an advantage depends on what you might need to do.

There are a couple other things that might be of consequence:

- passing a pointer makes it more obvious at the call site that the object might be modified. I consider this a reason to favor the pass-by-address syntax, all other things being equal.
- a reference cannot be 'reseated' to refer to a different object.  A pointer can be made to point to something else (unless you pass in an `ObjectType* const` pointer, which is pretty rare).
- overload resolution might be a factor.  For example, making operator overloads work naturally was one of the motivations for adding references to C++.

Comment: if pass by value or pass by reference works for me, which is better in terms of performance and portability

Comment: @user695242 - when you say 'pass by value' do you mean 'pass the address by value'?  Otherwise, 'pass by value' is something I didn't talk about in my answer (in 'pass by value' the object the caller passes in cannot be modified by the function, since the function gets a copy).

Comment: They are the exact same thing as far as the compiler is concerned at the machine language level ... references can be thought of as constant pointers that are initialized to the address of the object at the time of creation (hence they cannot be NULL, and cannot be changed to point to a different object).  References are also implicitly dereferenced when they are called.  You could think of references as implicit pointers rather than explicit pointers which must be explicitly dereferenced with the `*` operator.

Answer (score 2):

Memory allocation has nothing to do with type of formal parameters. Both functions,

```
void populateInfo ( struct studentInfo & student ); //1
void populateInfo ( struct studentInfo * student ); //2
```

can be called with object created in heap or in stack. The first implies that object already created, the second allows null argument.
Passing by reference is usually better because you avoid copying objects. However, for built-in types like `char`, `int`, etc it makes no difference from that point of view. Also, passing by reference lets you change value of argument.

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation with pointer will be more ressource efficient because the function only copies a reference (pointer) of the objet to work with.

The implementation with passing the object will create a copy of the object to use it in your function (so allocate more memory).

I suggest you to use const reference to your object in your function if you don't intend to modify it in your function:

Comment: I read in one of the C++ books, that 'const' reference is efficient way of doing it. But WHY ?